# How to use Microsoft.Win32.Registry.OpenSubKey to go directly to a particular key?

Tags: c#, registry, msdn

Now this is a simple question. It should be clearly documented in MSDN. I looked but I couldn't find it. The only thing I got was that I had to open subkey after subkey after subkey to get to the particular key I'm interested in.

Surely there is a more direct method to access a key 3 levels deep. What is it?

I've already tried

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft", true);  // reg is still HKLM !
```

and

```
reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\", true); // reg is still HKLM !
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are expecting the `OpenSubKey()` method to do something to `reg` - somehow to make it point to the sub key. It doesn't work that way. `OpenSubKey()` returns a new object of type  RegistryKey which can be used to retrieve the value of, or modify, the sub key. So you need:

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey subKey = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`OpenSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx) returns a new `RegistryKey` object :

```
reg = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft", true); // Will work or
var sub = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure just put your full path of that key, example:

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("the registry full path");
```