# registry key exists disable button

Tags: button, registry

no matter what i do if the key is there the button dont disable and i have no idea why this is the code i have for it currently

```
 //2012

        using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\Maya\2012"))
        {
            if (Key != null)
            {

                maya8.Text = "Maya 2012 Installed";
                maya8.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                maya8.Text = "Install maya 2012";
                maya8.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Autodesk\Maya\8.5"))
        {
            if (Key != null)
            {
                maya8.Text = "Maya 8.5 Installed";
                maya8.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                maya8.Text = "Install maya 8.5";
                maya8.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

and no matter that i do i get this issue and here is a screen of registry

[image: image of registry]

image of program when launched

[image: l]

thank you in advance elfenliedtopfan5

Answer (score 0):

See that you're referencing the local machine key, and then opening a sub key of that local machine key. The path to the sub key should be relative to the local machine key. That is, instead of the following:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Autodesk\Maya\8.5"))
```

Try this:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Autodesk\Maya\8.5"))
```

The answer was discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101340/how-to-use-microsoft-win32-registry-opensubkey-to-go-directly-to-a-particular-ke) by simply Googling for examples of the usage of this function!

Also note that your links aren't quite correct in your post. Check your markdown; note that you get a preview before posting!

Comment: thank you for your quick response :) but still have the same issue with it the button is still active when it should be grayed out as its installed on the machine and yeah i know the pics where not done right it would not let me post the images until i have 10 rep so i put spaces between .http and .png and it worked

Comment: Have you tried removing the "Wow6432Node\" portion of the path?

Comment: using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Autodesk\Maya\2012"))
            {
                if (Key != null)
                {

                    maya8.Text = "Maya 2012 Installed";
                    maya8.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    maya8.Text = "Install maya 2012";
                    maya8.Enabled = true;
                }
            } this is the one that is installed but still this one comes up with a active button and i did all the stuff to both of them

Comment: Are you referencing the correct button? You use maya8.* for all four code branches. I'd presume that there'd be two separate buttons? Also, please fix the capitalisation of Maya in your button texts; the inconsistency is bugging me! :)

Comment: lol i did not even realize about the buttons yeah for the maya8 and i have maya2012 for the other button i changed them all but still it dont disable it :( and i been trying to get this to work now for nearly a day i'm new to c# but cant see what im doing wrong here

Comment: Use the Visual Studio debug tool; set a breakpoint, hover over a variable to get a value, and work your way down the registry tree to see which paths exist?

Comment: this is what i get to when i debug it but dont see how this returns false its true god registry is so confusing https://winpic.co/2QC96e02